# Knockout Editable table issue

Tags: knockout.js

I've been working on a simple table editor using knockoutjs and jquery for editing simple timelines. My object model is like so:

```
var timelineEditor = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.rowCount = data.Cells.length;
    self.rows = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    self.filename = ko.observable(data.FileName);
    self.keyIdentifier = ko.observable(data.identifier);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.Cells.length; i++) {
        self.rows.push(new timelineEditorRow(data.Cells[i], self));
    }
};

var timelineEditorRow = function(dataRow, parent) {
    var self = this;
    var $parent = parent;
    self.cells = ko.observableArray([]);
    for (var i = 0; i < dataRow.length; i++) {
        self.cells.push(new timelineEditorCell(dataRow[i], self));
    }
};

var timelineEditorCell = function(dataCell, parent) {
    var self = this;
    var $parent = parent;
    self.text = ko.observable(dataCell.Text);
    self.isItemEditing = ko.observable(false);
    self.editItem = function() {
        self.isItemEditing(true);
    };
    self.finishEdit = function() {
        self.isItemEditing(false);
    }
};
```

I'm binding like so:

```
<div id="EditorDiv">
    <table data-bind="foreach: rows">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: cells">
            <td>
                <span data-bind ="text: text, visible: !isItemEditing(), click: editItem, blur: finishEdit"></span>
                <textarea  data-bind="text: text, visible: isItemEditing"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Now, when I click on any cell, the little editor shows up and things largely work. However, my issue is, how do I keep the span (for display) and the textarea (for editing) the same size? Obviously, I could set a width and height property, but because these are contained in a table, the height would need to be set by the row (the parent) and the width would need to be set by the table column (not currently in the hierarchy).

Any suggestions for how to reorganize the object model so that this is doable?

Comment: I don't see where the problem is if you use %-based width/ height on the span and textarea? You don't need to set a row-height? What is a table column? ( as far as I know there's only tr & td, and the 'column' is simply the td:nth-child in various tr's)

Comment: The users will be able to add columns, which is why I initially didn't want to do that. That said, I might be able to do something with that.

That's the thing with table columns. They don't really exist. Their width is derived from the width of the items in them.

Comment: Aha! It seems to me that you don't know about the `table-layout` property. Check it out [here](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_table-layout&preval=fixed). If you set it to `fixed`, you could easily give the columns a fixed/ relative width by styling the `td's` . If a preset width is not what you want, you could still adapt them dynamically onchange of the textarea content with some JS.

Comment: No, I didn't know about that. That has...possibilities.

Comment: Cool, hope that solves the question kinda. I don't see any problems with your Knockout code.. Btw tables with fixed lay-outs have the additional benefit of faster browser rendering. Good luck